# How to create a 3D array of a tuple of arrays in numpy, where each element of the 3D array is like the output of np.where?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D array where each axis is the same length (~100) and corresponds to a location in 3D space. Each element of this array has a value (float64). I am trying to create an array identifying neighbors where each element of this new 3D array consists of a tuple of arrays, similar to the output of np.where so that I can loop through each element of the 3D array and perform an operation on all the neighbors.

I know np.where for a 3D array would output a 3-tuple of arrays, where the length of each array is the same and is the number of elements satisfying the given condition. I'm trying to do something similar, but in my case I know that the length of these arrays is 6, since each element of the 3D array has 6 immediate neighbors. I want to set each element of the 3D neighbors array to be a tuple of 3 arrays of length 6.

What I would like to do is something like:

```
>>> values = np.zeros((100,100,100))
>>> neighbors = np.zeros((100,100,100))
>>> for i in range(neighbors.shape[0]):
>>>     for j in range(neighbors.shape[1]):
>>>         for k in range(neighbors.shape[2]):
>>>             neighbors[i,j,k] = (np.array([i-1,i+1,i,i,i,i]),np.array([j,j,j-1,j+1,j,j]),np.array([k,k,k,k,k-1,k+1]))
>>> neighbors[5,6,9]
(array([4,6,5,5,5,5]), array([6,6,5,7,6,6]), array([9,9,9,9,8,10]))
```

whereas what I actually get is the following error:

```
>>> values = np.zeros((100,100,100))
>>> neighbors = np.zeros((100,100,100))
>>> for i in range(neighbors.shape[0]):
>>>     for j in range(neighbors.shape[1]):
>>>         for k in range(neighbors.shape[2]):
>>>             neighbors[i,j,k] = (np.array([i-1,i+1,i,i,i,i]),np.array([j,j,j-1,j+1,j,j]),np.array([k,k,k,k,k-1,k+1]))
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Any way to set elements of an array as a tuple of arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store arbitrary Python objects in the cells of a NumPy array, change the dtype to `object`: Here, you would need to change

```
neighbors = np.zeros((100,100,100))
```

to

```
neighbors = np.zeros((100,100,100), dtype='O')
```

By default `np.zeros` creates an array of floating point dtype, which means every cell of the array must hold a floating point value, hence the error message:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

---

Beware that using arrays of `object` dtype inhibits NumPy from using fast numerical methods -- the code will be slower than equivalent NumPy code that uses arrays of native (e.g. floating point) dtype.

For example, you might be better off creating an array of *floating point dtype* and shape `(3,6,100,100,100)` where the first axis (of length 3) allows you to select amongst the three subarrays,

```
(array([4,6,5,5,5,5]), array([6,6,5,7,6,6]), array([9,9,9,9,8,10]))
```

and the second axis (of length 6) allows you to select amongst the 6 values in the subarray:

```
import numpy as np
d, h, w = 100, 100, 100
I, J, K = np.mgrid[:d, :h, :w]
neighbors = np.array([(I-1,I+1,I,I,I,I), (J,J,J-1,J+1,J,J), (K,K,K,K,K-1,K+1)])
```

Then `neighbors` is an array with a native NumPy dtype:

```
In [32]: neighbors.dtype
Out[32]: dtype('int64')

In [33]: neighbors.shape
Out[33]: (3, 6, 100, 100, 100)
```

Here are the three subarrays, corresponding to your `neighbors[5,6,9]`:

```
In [36]: neighbors[:,:,5,6,9]
Out[36]: 
array([[ 4,  6,  5,  5,  5,  5],
       [ 6,  6,  5,  7,  6,  6],
       [ 9,  9,  9,  9,  8, 10]])
```

Here is the second of these subarrays, corresponding to your `neighbors[5,6,9][1]`:

```
In [37]: neighbors[1,:,5,6,9]
Out[37]: array([6, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6])
```

And here is the fourth value in the second subarray, corresponding to your `neighbors[5,6,9][1][3]`:

```
In [38]: neighbors[1,3,5,6,9]
Out[38]: 7
```

Comment: Would that still allow me to use fancy indexing to perform an operation on the values of neighbors? E.g., `np.average(values[neighbors[5,6,9]])`, which is ultimately my goal.

Comment: In terms of performance, would I still get the benefits of numpy if I'm only operating on the tuple of each element itself as in that example, since I wouldn't be operating on the entire neighbors object but just the elements which are tuples of arrays?

Comment: To answer my own question, yes, something like `np.average(values[neighbors[5,6,9]])` does work when setting the neighbors dtype to object.